# How can I change the query string used in pages showing search results from keys=football to keyword=football?

Tags: search, uri, 10

Search results are given in a page whose URL is, for example, https://example.com/search/node?keys=football. This URL is not recognized by Google Analytics as a search result URL.

How can I change the search URL to https://example.com/search/node?keyword=football?

Comment: If you're using a view for your search page, they query key is part of the configuration for a filter. You can change it to whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URLs output by Drupal can be altered by a tagged service that uses a class which implements two interfaces: [`OutboundPathProcessorInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PathProcessor%21OutboundPathProcessorInterface.php/interface/OutboundPathProcessorInterface/9) and [`InboundPathProcessorInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PathProcessor%21InboundPathProcessorInterface.php/interface/InboundPathProcessorInterface/9). (I use links for Drupal 9 documentation pages simply because the Drupal 10 documentation pages do not yet show all the parameter descriptions.)

You can use the code used for the [path_alias.path_processor](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21path_alias%21path_alias.services.yml/service/path_alias.path_processor/9) service (the one that handles path aliases) as example code.

#### .services.yml

```yaml
services:
  path_alias.path_processor:
    class: Drupal\path_alias\PathProcessor\AliasPathProcessor
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 100 }
      - { name: path_processor_outbound, priority: 300 }
    arguments: ['@path_alias.manager']
```

#### Service class

```php
class AliasPathProcessor implements InboundPathProcessorInterface, OutboundPathProcessorInterface {

  /**
   * An alias manager for looking up the system path.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface
   */
  protected $aliasManager;

  /**
   * Constructs a AliasPathProcessor object.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface $alias_manager
   *   An alias manager for looking up the system path.
   */
  public function __construct(AliasManagerInterface $alias_manager) {
    $this->aliasManager = $alias_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {
    $path = $this->aliasManager->getPathByAlias($path);
    return $path;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processOutbound($path, &$options = [], Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {
    if (empty($options['alias'])) {
      $langcode = isset($options['language']) ? $options['language']->getId() : NULL;
      $path = $this->aliasManager->getAliasByPath($path, $langcode);

      // Ensure the resulting path has at most one leading slash, to prevent it
      // becoming an external URL without a protocol like //example.com. This
      // is done in \Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator::generateFromRoute()
      // also, to protect against this problem in arbitrary path processors,
      // but it is duplicated here to protect any other URL generation code
      // that might call this method separately.
      if (strpos($path, '//') === 0) {
        $path = '/' . ltrim($path, '/');
      }
    }
    return $path;
  }

}
```

[`processOutbound()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PathProcessor%21OutboundPathProcessorInterface.php/function/OutboundPathProcessorInterface%3A%3AprocessOutbound/9) changes the URLs output by Drupal. The query values are passed in `$options['query']`. To change the *keys* value to *keyword*, you just need to use code similar to the following one.

```php
if (isset($options['query']['keys'])) {
  $keys = $options['query']['keys'];
  unset($options['query']['keys']);
  $options['query']['keyword'] = $keys;
}
```

You also need to check the path is the one you expect, for example with `if ($path == '/search/node') { /* … */ }`.

[`processInbound()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PathProcessor%21InboundPathProcessorInterface.php/function/InboundPathProcessorInterface%3A%3AprocessInbound/9) changes the URLs received from Drupal before it can handle them. The query parameters are returned from `$request->query->get()` (for example, `$request->query->get('keyword')`). A query parameter is set with `$request->query->set()` (for example, `$request->query->set('keyword', $request->query->get('keys'))`).

You will also need to set the priority of your *path_processor_inbound* lower than the one used by *path_alias.path_processor* (so it is executed after it), and the priority of your *path_processor_outbound* higher than the one used by *path_alias.path_processor* (so it is executed before it, and it gets the original path, not the path alias, in `$path`).

This method works also in the case the search page showing the results is overridden by a view.